# gapi.drive.share.ShareClient fails when there are Multiple Account Logins

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I'm getting the following error:

"Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time.  Please try again later".

I'm using the following code

```
var shareClient = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient(this.appId);
    shareClient.setOAuthToken(gapi.auth.getToken().access_token);
    shareClient.setItemIds([id]);
    shareClient.showSettingsDialog();
```

The console is showing the following error:

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://docs.google.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://example.com').

Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol=gadgets&origin=...

This error only occur when using GSuite account and logging with multiple accounts (for example, my personal account and my business GSuite account)

Using my personal account works fine in the same setup

I've found old question regarding similar problem back in 2014. Google fixed that (by introducing setOAuthToken function). So, it seems like those old problems are not related to my current issue

Thanks

Update:

I found out that only the first account logged to Google works with share client (no matter its type)

For example:

(1) Logged in as user X

(2) Logged in as user Y

(3) Call ShareClient as user X (works)

(4) Call ShareClient as user Y (fails)

Sing out from these two accounts then do reverse

(1) Logged in as user Y

(2) Logged in as user X

(3) Call ShareClient as user Y (works)

(4) Call ShareClient as user X (fails)